# How to reassign global object from inside a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I don't seem like the variable game outside of createNewGame is updated with the same value as the game inside of createNewGame.

Is there any way I can update the global game inside of the createNewGame function?

```
export let game = new Game(settings);

export const createNewGame = (updatedSettings) => {
  game = new Game(Object.assign(settings, updatedSettings), true)
  game.test = 'test'
  //reset state
  runGame(game);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside this module, the value of `game` will be updated when you call `createNewGame()`.  That's pretty easy to test and verify.

But, I see you are exporting `game`.  When someone uses that export, they are getting the current value of the `game` variable and they are putting that current value into their own variable.  When you then assign a new value to this local `game` variable in this module when `createNewGame()` is called, the module that used the `export` will still have the original value of that `game` variable in their variable.  Their own variable that they assigned the exported value into will not be updated.

The way around that would be to export an object that does not change and make the `game` be a property on that object.

```
export let gameObj = { game: new Game(settings) };

export const createNewGame = (updatedSettings) => {
  gameObj.game = new Game(Object.assign(settings, updatedSettings), true)
  gameObj.game.test = 'test'
  //reset state
  runGame(gameObj.game);
}
```

This works because you aren't reassigning `gameObj`, just a property on that object.  So, both your local `gameObj` and anyone who used the exported `gameObj` will both have references to the same `gameObj` object.  And, when you change the `gameObj.game` property, then both the local reference and the exported reference will see the new value of that property.